# Remove ActionBar items from the Toolbar

Tags: android

I read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) regarding the ActionBar (App Bar). It states:

> In its most basic form, the action bar displays the title for the
>   activity on one side and an overflow menu on the other (the
>   three-dotted flyout menu).
>
> app bar features have gradually been added to the native ActionBar
>   over various Android releases. As a result, the native ActionBar
>   behaves differently depending on what version of the Android system a
>   device may be using. **By contrast, the most recent features are added
>   to the support library's version of Toolbar**. **For this reason, you
>   should use the support library's Toolbar class to implement your
>   activities' app bars**.

So basically it is telling me that to use the Toolbar not Actionbar when I want to customize the App Bar. I heed the advice and add a toolbar:

build.gradle (Module:app) file:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

res/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  </style>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout ... android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <ImageView android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/yourStory" android:src="@drawable/ic_face_black_24dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**It appears that the ActionBar is baked into the Toolbar because the overflow menu appears even though I did not specify it in the Toolbar**. Also, the title of my application remains. The image within the Toolbar rightly appears.

Now it's important for me to note that I did inflate the menu items in order for them to appear:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And in menu/main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/camera" android:title="Camera"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/logo" android:title="Logo"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/profile" android:title="Profile"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

If I get rid of those items, the flyout menu goes away. So apparently, the ActionBar is integrated into the Toolbar. But how do I get rid of the title on the Toolbar? I don't know where that is coming from. My ultimate goal is to create the Toolbar similar to Instagram. On the left it has an icon of a camera, in center a logo and on right another icon.

Comment: Did you try calling `setTitle("")` on your `Toolbar`? BTW, what makes you think that Instagram is even using `Toolbar`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I figured it out and posted answer below. I am keeping this question open still, because the Android docs throw around terms like ActionBar, ToolBar and App Bar so loosely and to a Newbie it can be difficult grasping all the concepts. I finally made sense of it all and hopefully it benefits someone else.

Comment: @CommonsWare and what else would Instagram be using? I am talking about the screen on the home page. It has an icon of camera to left, logo in center, and another icon on right. Why would you need something else to accomplish that?

Comment: Well, "logo in center" violates the Material Design guidelines, last I checked. Hence, I would not be surprised if that is not really supported. As for "what else would Instagram be using", candidates include `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, or `ConstraintLayout`, with widgets inside of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can customize your `Toolbar` as below:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#fff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/camera"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/Instagram_logo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Write below lines of code in your `activity` class, to hide default toolbar `title` and handling `click` events of `camera` and `send` option:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

ImageView imageCamera = (ImageView) toolBar.findViewById(R.id.camera);
ImageView imageSend = (ImageView) toolBar.findViewById(R.id.send);

imageCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something
    }
});

imageSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: @Donato If my answer seems useful then please give an up-vote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found some clarity on the matter. There is a line of code that integrates the ActionBar into the ToolBar and it is `setSuppertActionBar`. And once that integration occurs, then you can begin calling ActionBar methods on the Toolbar as so:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
// Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
// We do not want to display title, which is a default for the ActionBar
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```